# Urlib BeautifulSoup python 3.3 page specific error

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, urllib

```
from urllib.request import urlopen 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
content = urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_human_stampedes")
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
print(soup.get_text())
print(soup.prettify())
```

**error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sony\Desktop\Trash\Crawler Try\try3.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(soup.get_text())
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u014d' in position 10487: character maps to <undefined>
[Finished in 2.1s with exit code 1]
```

Seems to be page specific for eg. I get this in case replacing url by http://www.quora.com

Comment: This has nothing to do with either `urllib` or BeautifulSoup; you are printing Unicode to a console that is not configured to handle it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am new to python I don't understand it. I am using Sublime Text 2.

Comment: Your console is configured to handle Windows Codepage 1252, and U+014D characters cannot be encoded to CP1252. See the duped post.

Comment: what's the workaround? Should I get change the console. I don't happen to understand the answers there.